# Bootstrap-table - Modify fields with bootstrap modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I continue with my new website and I'm trying the bootstrap framework and I would like modify a row, its fields, from a bootstrap modal window. At moment I show a modal windows with fields but I don't know to include the data from the row of the table :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>AddCloud - Producció</title>

    <!-- INCLUDES -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css">
    <script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>      

        <!-- SESSION PHP OK -->

    <?php   
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] <> ''){
    ?>



        <!-- NAVIGATION -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.addvantage.es"><font color=#8abe44>AddCloud</font></a></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="edicions.php">Producció<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="underconstruction.html">Menu2</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>  preferències</a></li>
                    <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>  canviar password</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>  log out</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </nav>



        <!-- TABLE -->

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
              <h1 class="text-center">Miquel Alimentació</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><h3>Edició 12</h3></div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <?php  
                    // Conexió a la base de dades
                    include("connect.php");  
                    $conn = Conectarse("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");  
                    //query
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_origen ORDER BY id_articulo ASC";
                    $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  
                    //se despliega el resultado  
                    echo "<table id='tableprod'
                                   data-toggle='table'
                                   data-toolbar='#toolbar'
                                   data-show-refresh='true'
                                   data-show-toggle='true'
                                   data-sort-name='name'
                                   data-sort-order='desc'
                                   data-show-columns='true'
                                   data-pagination='true'
                                   data-search='true'
                                   data-click-to-select='true'>";
                        echo "<thead class='thead-inverse'>";
                            echo "<tr>";  
                                echo "<th data id='seleccion' data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>";  
                                echo "<th data id='pagina' data-sortable='true'>pagina</th>";  
                                echo "<th data id='codigo' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>codigo</th>";  
                                echo "<th data id='descripcion' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>descripcion</th>";  
                                echo "<th data id='pvp-cat' data-sortable='true'>pvp-cat</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='pvp-lev' data-sortable='true'>pvp-lev</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='pvp-and' data-sortable='true'>pvp-and</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='pvp-cen' data-sortable='true'>pvp-cen</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='pvp-nor' data-sortable='true'>pvp-nor</th>"; 
                                echo "<th data id='pvp-vas' data-sortable='true'>pvp-vas</th>";  
                                echo "<th data id='fecha-mod' data-sortable='true'>fecha-mod</th>";
                                echo "<th data id='user' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>user</th>";
                                echo "<th data id='edit' data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>edit</th>";
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                        echo "</thead>"; 
                        echo "<tbody>";
                    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){   
                            echo "<tr>";  
                                echo "<td></td>";
                                echo "<td>$row[2]></td>";  
                                echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";  
                                echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";  
                                echo "<td>$row[5]</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>$row[6]</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>$row[7]></td>";  
                                echo "<td>$row[8]</td>";  
                                echo "<td>$row[9]</td>";  
                                echo "<td>$row[10]</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>$row[11]</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>$row[12]</td>";
                                echo "<td><p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button></p></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";  
                    }  
                        echo "</tbody>";
                    echo "</table>";  
                ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
              <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 &middot; All Rights Reserved &middot; <a href="http://www.addvantage.es/" >http://www.addvantage.es</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>



        <!-- MODAL MENU -->   

        <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Editar registre</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Pàgina">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Codi">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Descripció">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="pvp-cat">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="pvp-lev">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="pvp-and">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="pvp-cen">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="pvp-nor">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="pvp-vas">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>


        <!-- SESSION PHP ERROR -->        
<?php
    } else{
        ?><p>La sesión no está activa, por favor ingrese <a href="login.html">aquí</a></p>
<?php
    }?>


</body>
</html>
```

I use php to connect to database and add data into the table. My idea is from a edit button can modify this fields from a modal window. After that I would like to update database.

I'm not sure if this is the best way, I haven't a experience programming from web environment.

Please Could you help me to modify this data-fields from windows modal?

Thanks!

Comment: you can display data but not edit it and update database with edited data?

Comment: Yes, the problem is this. I show data correctly but I cann't edit and update database :(

Comment: you want to edit data displayed in table in a modal that you open, right?

Comment: Yes this is the question

Answer (score 0):

The way to try to do is correct. What you have to do is on clicking Edit link find the closest tr and find all the td that tr contain. Read td one by one the assign it to the text box.

Below is the code:

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr"), $tds = $row.find("td"); //This will all the tds we need.
  $.each($tds, function() {
    $('#txtbox').val($(this).text()); //textbox in the modal window
  });
});
```

The above code will fill all the values from the row to modal window after that you can modify and submit the form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to understand your code.

Comment: Sorry but I don'understand well the last line. What it mean exactly? '#txtbox'? And How I do to reference with my form?

Comment: I have changed the line of the code: $('#txtbox').val($(this).text()) by $('#txtbox').val("1") and doesn't show 1. I think that doesn't working fine :( Also I tried to put the value directly not each... but it doesn't working fine too.

Comment: $('#textbox') is your textfield in modal window. In your modal window you have textbox <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Codi"> your code should be $('#cod').val($(this).text());

Comment: It doesn't work. This code $('#cod')? The placeholder(Codi) of the input class isn't a id or name to identify Javascript, not? Apart from this I'm trying a simple code: $('.edit').click(function(){
                   $('#codi').val('1'); and doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

First step - identify row somehow. I'm working **under assumption that $row[0] is the id of that row in the database**. If it isn't change the code accordingly.

**index.php**

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){   
    echo "<tr id="{$row[0]}">";  // assign id that corresponds to database id to each row
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td class="pagina">$row[2]></td>";  
        echo "<td class="codigo">$row[3]</td>";  
        echo "<td class="descripcion">$row[4]</td>";  
        echo "<td class="pvp-cat">$row[5]</td>"; 
        echo "<td class="pvp-lev">$row[6]</td>"; 
        echo "<td class="pvp-and">$row[7]></td>";  
        echo "<td class="pvp-cen">$row[8]</td>";  
        echo "<td class="pvp-nor">$row[9]</td>";  
        echo "<td class="pvp-vas">$row[10]</td>"; 
        echo "<td class="fecha-mod">$row[11]</td>"; 
        echo "<td class="user">$row[12]</td>";
        echo "<td>
                <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'>
                    <button class='edit' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </td>";
    echo "</tr>";  
}
```

Second, set jquery click event to copy values from rows and fill the modal input fields with correct values:

**JQUERY**

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
  var row = $(this).closest("tr"), // edit button is in the same row as data you want to change
      tds = row.find("td"); // get all table cells in that row

  $.each(tds, function(index) {
    if( $.inArray(index, [0, 10, 11, 12]) ) { // indexes of cells not to be used when getting data from table cells to edit
      return; // skip to next loop iteration if one of these indexes
    }

    var input_name = $(this).attr("class"); // get name of cell we are evaluating (pagina, codigo, descripcion etc)

    $([name='"' + input_name + '"']).val($(this).text()); //input name in the modal window
  });
});
```

I've changed the modal to reflect changes in code above.

**MODAL**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Editar registre</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="/store.php">
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" type="text"> <!-- hidden input for id -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="pagina" type="text" placeholder="Pàgina">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="codigo" type="text" placeholder="Codi">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="descripcion" type="text" placeholder="Descripció">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="pvp-cat" type="text" placeholder="pvp-cat">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="pvp-lev" type="text" placeholder="pvp-lev">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="pvp-and" type="text" placeholder="pvp-and">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="pvp-cen" type="text" placeholder="pvp-cen">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="pvp-nor" type="text" placeholder="pvp-nor">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="pvp-vas" type="text" placeholder="pvp-vas">
                        </div>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="width: 100%;" value="Update">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

File for storing edited values to the database:

**store.php**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $pagina = $_POST['pagina'];
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $pvp-cat = $_POST['pvp-cat'];
    $pvp-lev = $_POST['pvp-lev'];
    $pvp-and = $_POST['pvp-and'];
    $pvp-cen = $_POST['pvp-cen'];
    $pvp-nor = $_POST['pvp-nor'];
    $pvp-vas = $_POST['pvp-vas'];

    $sql = "UPDATE produccion.ma_origen SET pagina='{$pagina}',codigo='{$codigo}',descripcion='{$descripcion}',
                pvp-cat='{$pvp-cat}', pvp-lev='{$pvp-lev}',pvp-and='{$pvp-and}',
                pvp-cen='{$pvp-cen}',pvp-nor='{$pvp-nor}',pvp-vas='{$pvp-vas}'
                WHERE id={$id}";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Since this was a lot of code to change and I don't have the time and all the data to test this properly you'll have to do it, but this is one of the ways you could solve your problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thaks a lot! I'm goint to revise your code and try it. Thanks again :)

Comment: np. If you have a question regarding code or something is not right write here and I'll check it out.

Comment: The code does not works. The IDE detect an error in the command continue. A part of this I do not understand the code of jquery :(

Comment: Since I don't have all the data and means to test this code I've written it more as an idea of how to solve this. But it needs a bit of debugging with real data. I've updated the jquery part with comments.
continue statement: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: To testing, I comment all jquery lines in the web page and only I put this: $('#edit').click(function(){ alert("It works!"); This code would open a windows with an alert message but it doesn't works! No it show any messages :(

Comment: What does it mean this line: $([name="id"]).val(row.attr("id"));?

Comment: I think that I found a problem. When I do clic in the edit button doesn't in to the function of javascript. I am sure because I have changed all lines in the function and only there are write alert("It's works") and if it works when I put into the button the event onclick... but it's not case

Comment: I think the error was that i've put id="edit" instead of class="edit" (I've changed jquery and index.php code to reflect that). I think that line is left over from something I've tried and forgot to delete it.

Comment: It doesn't works again. I have tried a new html document and I have put two textboxes, an edit button and a modal window to show the data of the textboxes and it's working fine!! I do not understand well why it not work in the document index.php :( There are some thing wrong!?

Comment: did you create the table with random data in a and added edit button or just edit button to open the modal?

Comment: I created two textfields with the text: 1 and 2 after there are a edit button. When I push the edit button show me a modal windows with two new text fields with the text: 1 and 2.

Comment: ok. tnx. Since I'm working now I'll take a look at my code once again today in the evening or tomorrow morning, correct mistakes and edit answer to reflect changes. From what I've gathered from your comments the error is probably in jquery code

Comment: Finally I have not found the problem :(